# Configuring a Gradle task based on task to be executed

Tags: gradle

I'm seemingly in a bit of a chicken/egg problem.  I have the test task that Gradle defines with the `Java` plugin.  I set the JUnit categories to run using a property.  My team has expressed interest in a task that will run tasks in a specific category instead of having to use -P to set a property on the command line.

I can't come up with a way to pull this off since the new task would need to configure the `test` task *only if it's executed*.  Since the categories to run need to be a input parameter for the test task to make sure the UP-TO-DATE check functions correctly, they need to be set during the configuration phase and can't wait for the execution phase.

Does anyone know how to make a setup like this work?  Maybe I'm approaching it from the wrong angle entirely.

***Edit 1***

Current build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

def defaultCategory = 'checkin'

test {
    def category = (project.hasProperty('category') ? project['category'] : defaultCategory)
    inputs.property('category', category)

    useJUnit()
    options {
        includeCategories category
    }
}
```

What I'd like, but doesn't work:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

def defaultCategory = 'checkin'

test {
    def category = (project.hasProperty('category') ? project['category'] : defaultCategory)
    inputs.property('category', category)

    useJUnit()
    options {
        includeCategories category
    }
}

task nightly(dependsOn: 'build') {
    defaultCategory = 'nightly'
}

task weekly(dependsOn: 'build') {
    defaultCategory = 'weekly'
}
```

Since both tasks are configured regardless of whether they will be run, they become useless.  I can't defer setting the defaultCategory value until the execution phase because it's value is needed to configure the task inputs of the `test` task and because the value is required to be able to run the `test` task, which runs before the `build` task.

Comment: Could you please provide sample script showing where you have problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know if I'd call this solution elegant, but it has proven to be effective:

```
task nightly(dependsOn: 'build')

test {
    useJUnit()

    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
        if (gradle.taskGraph.hasTask(":${project.name}:nightly")) {
            options {
                includeCategories 'nightly'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact great solution but does not work at least with Gradle 6.2.2. hasTask() has some obvious problems (both string and task interface).

Comment: @RomanNikitchenko Worked fine here. I just omitted `:${project.name}`, because I don't have a multi-module build.

Comment: @RomanNikitchenko Works for me with Gradle 7.6, what was the issue you were seeing with Gradle 6.2.2 ?